# No HttpMessageConverter for org.springframework.http.HttpEntity and content type "multipart/form-data" error when uploading MultipartFile

Tags: java, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I followed all the steps from here to upload a multipart file: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload.

The issue is that I get a 500 HTTP code, **No HttpMessageConverter for org.springframework.http.HttpEntity and content type "multipart/form-data"**.

I searched about the error and it was suggested to add an additional converter to handle Multipart file upload. But I think it should work out of the box with built-in instruments.

Here is the upload file method:

```
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add(file.getName(), file);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders);
        return super.httpClient.doPostRequest(httpHeaders, myEndpoint, requestEntity, String.class, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    }
```

In doPostRequest I do the following - set the headers content type, create an entity and call the exchange method from restTemplate, returning the body:

```
        httpHeaders.setContentType(contentType);
        HttpEntity<B> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<T> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, responseType);
        return result.getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you wrap your body twice in a HttpEntity.

Once in your upload file method :

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders);
```

Once in your doPostRequest method :

```
HttpEntity<B> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders);
```

In the end you are sending a

> HttpEntity<HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>>

through the exchange method instead of a

> HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>

Comment: Pardon me if this is a silly question, but how to fix the problem? Change upload file method or change `doPostRequest` method or both?

Comment: The problem here is that "new HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders)" is done twice.

To fix the problem you can change either one, it's up to you to choose which one to change.

In this particular case, in order to avoid code duplication, I think it might be better to keep the code as it is in the doPostRequest, and remove the line with the "new HttpEntity" part in the uploadFile method. This way all the callers to doPostRequest won't have to handle the "new HttpEntity" part.

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] your answer and add your clarifications?